# Is there are way to create method level constants without namespace polution?

Tags: scala, coding-style

For example I want to filter object by some field values.
I can write

```
objects.filter{ o =>
   val set = Set(c1,c2)
   set contains o.field
}
```

in that case I will create hashset each time method called ==> it will be slow

I also can write this way

```
val set = Set(c1,c2)
objects.filter{ o =>
   set contains o.field
}
```

It will work fast but I pollute my space with meaningless object `set`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
objects.filter {
  val set = Set(c1,c2)
  o => set contains o.field
}
```

If you will factor out "Set(c1,c2)" into a def like this:

```
def getSet = { println("Set!"); Set(5,7)}
```

You would see that there is only one set created.

Answer (score 7):

Just put braces around it, and namespace is no longer polluted.

```
{
  val set = Set(c1,c2)
  objects.filter{ o =>
    set contains o.field
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use inner named functions, they help better structure the code and keep namespace clean.

```
def someMeaningfulName = {
  val set = Set(c1,c2)
  objects.filter{ o =>
    set contains o.field
  }
}
```